# how to detect device orientation is supported by modernizr?

Tags: html, modernizr, device-orientation

Can anyone tel me how to check whether device orientation is supported by modernizr (eg:modernizr.geolocation) in html file. I need to check the browser supports that feature device orientation or not. Any help?

Comment: if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent || window.OrientationEvent || typeof window.onorientationchange != 'undefined') {-----
} ---am checking like this here for browser support. I want to use modernizr to check the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Modernizr.hasEvent('deviceOrientation')` although you need to ensure that the Modernizr version you have built includes this (include 'event-deviceorientation' in the 'Non-core detects' box).